# Способы вывода табличных данных

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Нужно создать таблицу для вывода данных наподобие: 
http://www.csharpkey.com/visualcsharp/adonet/forms/employees5.jpg

Как можно это сделать? Есть ли какие-то сторонние библиотеки, которые позволяют сделать это легко или же можно сделать это с помощью стандартных библиотек Windows?

Comment: Если вам нужен графический вывод информации, почему бы вам не перейти на C#/WPF?

Answer (score 1):

В той же visual-studio, судя по меткам, есть стандарные компоненты для работы с таблицами
DBGrid, если нужно редактировать, или StringGrid/DrawGrid, если просто отображение.